# What is difference between sys.exit(0) and os._exit(0)

Tags: python

Please help me in clarifying the concept of these two python statements in terms of difference in functionality:

1. `sys.exit(0)`
2. `os._exit(0)`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os._exit):

> ```
> os._exit():
> ```
>
> Exit the process with status n, without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc.
>
> **Note** The standard way to exit is `sys.exit(n)`. `_exit()` should normally only be used in the child process after a `fork()`.

Comment: Could someone expand on, "should normally only be used in the child process after a fork()"?  Thanks

Answer (score 52):

`os._exit` calls the C function `_exit()` which does an immediate program
termination. Note the statement "can never return".

`sys.exit()` is identical to `raise SystemExit()`. It raises a Python
exception which may be caught by the caller.

Original post: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/156121-os-_exit-vs-sys-exit

Comment: What is the disadvantage of having immediate program termination?

Answer (score 9):

Excerpt from the book "The linux Programming Interface":

Programs generally don’t call `_exit()` directly, but instead call the `exit()` library function,
which performs various actions before calling `_exit()`.

- Exit handlers (functions registered with `at_exit()` and `on_exit()`) are called, in
  reverse order of their registration
- The stdio stream buffers are flushed.
- The `_exit()` system call is invoked, using the value supplied in status.

---

**Could someone expand on why `_exit()` should normally only be used in the child process after a fork()?**

Instead of calling `exit()`, the child can call `_exit()`, so that it doesn’t flush stdio
buffers. This technique exemplifies a more general principle: in an application
that creates child processes, typically only one of the processes (most often the
parent) should terminate via `exit()`, while the other processes should terminate
via `_exit()`. This ensures that only one process calls exit handlers and flushes
stdio buffers, which is usually desirable

Comment: "This ensures that only one process calls exit handlers and flushes stdio buffers, which is usually desirable"

Why is that desirable?

Comment: Doesn't each program have its own stdio buffer? Why would not flushing the stdio buffers of the child processes be a good thing?