# How to completely exit a server in python?

Tags: python

How to exit a server completely in Python? Code like `server.shutdown()` just shuts down the incoming requests. Can anyone suggest any code for complete exit of server? It's a simple socketserver.

This is my code for server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
from threading import Thread

class sockServer:

    def __init__(self,port):
        self.socket= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.bind(port)
        self.socket.listen(5)

    def _run(self):
        while True:
            request, client_address =self.socket.accept()
            counter=self.req_thread(self,request)
            counter.start()

    class req_thread(Thread):
        def __init__(self,controller,request):
            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.controller=controller
            self.request=request
            self.setDaemon(True)

        def run(self):
            input=self.request.makefile('rb',0)
            output=self.request.makefile('wb',0)
            l=True
            i=0
            try:
                while l:
            l=input.readline()
            if l!="exit\r\n":
                        print "x"
                        output.write(bytes('hello\n'))
                    else:
            print "y"
                        self.request.shutdown(2)
            run=False

            except socket.error:
                pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print('Usage: %s [hostname] [port number]' % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)
    hostname = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])
    global run
    run=True
    while run:
        server=sockServer((hostname,port))
        server._run()
```

The method using the variable `run` isn't doing any good!

Comment: Fix the formatting of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sys.exit isn't working then you can use a more extreme version which directly calls the os.

```
import os
os._exit()
```

You will have to do this if the server has forked a new process or thread. Which is what you are doing and why sys.exit isn't working as you expect. See this explanation of the difference between the two calls: [What is difference between sys.exit(0) and os._exit(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591350/what-is-difference-between-sys-exit0-and-os-exit0)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to exit the program completely then you can always add `import sys` and then in do this:

```
class req_thread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,controller,request):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.controller=controller
        self.request=request
        self.setDaemon(True)

    def run(self):
        input=self.request.makefile('rb',0)
        output=self.request.makefile('wb',0)
        l=True
        i=0
        try:
            while l:
                l=input.readline()
                if l!="exit\r\n":
                    print "x"
                    output.write(bytes('hello\n'))
                else:
                    print "y"
                    self.request.shutdown(2)
                    sys.exit(0)
                    run=False

        except socket.error:
            pass
```