# Stop Python code without an error

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have a piece of code which is not in a function, say

```
x = 5
y = 10
if x > 5:
    print("stopping")
```

What can I put after the print statement to stop the code from running further? Sys.exit() works, but raises an error that I don't want in the program. I want it to quietly stop the code as if it had reached the end of the main loop. Thanks.

Comment: Python always raise SystemError on exit. You are probably catching everything in an `except` block. And you shouldn't do that

Comment: @JBernardo: Good point. You mean `SystemExit`, though. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As JBernardo pointed out, **`sys.exit()` raises an exception**. This exception is [SystemExit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit). When it is not handled by the user code, the interpreter exits cleanly (a debugger debugging the program can catch it and keep control of the program, thanks to this mechanism, for instance)—as opposed to `os._exit()`, which is an unconditional abortion of the program.

This exception is **not caught by `except Exception:`**, because `SystemExit` does not inherit from `Exception`.  However, it *is caught* by a naked `except:` clause.

So, if your program sees an exception, you may want to catch fewer exceptions by using `except Exception:` instead of `except:`. That said, catching all exceptions is discouraged, because this might hide real problems, so avoid it if you can, by making the `except` clause (if any) more specific.

My understanding of why **this `SystemExit` exception mechanism is useful** is that the user code goes through any `finally` clause *after* a `sys.exit()` found in an `except` clause: files can be closed cleanly, etc.; then the interpreter catches any `SystemExit` that was not caught by the user and exits for good (a debugger would instead catch it so as to keep the interpreter running and obtain information about the program that exited).

Comment: I don't know! seriously! maybe the same person that down voted my answer.

Comment: Thank you! very informative. The intricacies of this have boggled my mind for some time, so it's nice to have a fresh view on it.

Comment: Is `exit()` same as `os._exit()`?

Comment: @jurgenreza, if you are referring to `sys.exit()`, then, no, they are different, as explained in the answer.

Comment: @EOL No i am referring to `exit()`.

Comment: If you are referring to the built-in `exit()` which is added when the interpreter is run without the -S option, then `exit()` is *different*  from `os._exit()`. `exit()` is similar to `sys.exit()`: [it raises SystemExit](http://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module). Note that it is [not recommended](http://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module) to use it in programs.

Answer (score 6):

You can do what you're looking for by doing this:

```
import os
os._exit(1)
```

Comment: This function is bad and you shouldn't be using it

Comment: why did you suggest os._exit and not sys.exit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591350/what-is-difference-between-sys-exit0-and-os-exit0

Comment: @Paul: He asked for a way to exit without raising an exception. Python will always raise an exception when using sys.exit. I agree that this isn't the way things should be done, but that's the answer to this question.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk: The reason why `os._exit()` causes problem is that it bypasses `finally` clean-up clauses. For instance, with `os._exit()`, a debugger would stop debugging the program because it loses control of it. That said, your answer *is* an answer to the question. I would only recommend it as a last resort, though, since it *unconditionally* makes the interpreter stop.

Comment: You can loose data on open files and other crazy stuff may happen

Comment: This function is not "bad": it's not deprecated, it doesn't, when used correctly, do any damage, and it's a deliberately exposed part of the API. It is the right function to use in various, very limited circumstances. sys.exit() is nearly always the correct answer though, as it is here.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.exit()` which is equivalent to `sys.exit(0)` means exit with success. `sys.exit(1)` or `sys.exit("Some message")` means exit with failure. Both cases raise a `SystemExit` exception. In fact when your program exists normally it is exactly like `sys.exit(0)` has been called.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran across this thread, I was looking for a way to exit the program without an error, without an exception, have the code show as 'PASSED', and continue running other tests files.  The solution, for me, was to use the **return** statement.

```
.
.
.
    if re.match("^[\s\S]*gdm-simple-slave[\s\S]*$", driver.find_element_by_css_selector("BODY").text) == None:
        print "Identifiers object gdm-simple-slave not listed in table"
        return
    else:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='gdm-simple-slave']").click()
.
.
.
```

That allowed me to run multiple programs while keeping the debugger running...

```
test_logsIdentifiersApache2EventWindow.py@16::test_LogsIdentifiersApache2EventWi
ndow **PASSED**
test_logsIdentifiersAudispdEventWindow.py@16::test_LogsIdentifiersAudispdEventWi
ndow **PASSED**
test_logsIdentifiersGdmSimpleSlaveEventWindow.py@16::test_LogsIdentifiersGdmSimp
leSlaveEventWindow Identifiers object gdm-simple-slave not listed in table
**PASSED**
test_logsIdentifiersAuditdEventWindow.py@16::test_LogsIdentifiersAuditdEventWind
ow **PASSED**
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [**try-except statements**](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
for x in xrange(0,5):
    try:
        print a[x+1] #this is a faulty statement for test purposes
    except:
        exit()

print "This is the end of the program."
```

**Output:**

```
> python test.py
2
3
4
5
```

No errors printed, despite the error raised.

Comment: `exit()` still raises `SystemError`.

Comment: I know that, which is why I wrote "despite the error raised."

Comment: @EOL You meant `SystemExit` :)

Comment: Despite specificity of the exception handling, an error *is* raised -- alright, I think we all agree.  But he wanted to exit *quietly* more than anything. By "quiet," I assumed he meant "without showing error.  So I agree with you guys, but I wrote the code according to my interpretation of his task.

Comment: @Mr_Spock: the code in the question does not show an error per se either (it only prints a string): I understand that the problem is not to write code that does not raise an (non-SystemExit) exception, but to either exit unconditionally or to handle SystemExit silently.

Comment: I see.  Yeah, after reading the OP's posts, I realized that.  So now, I don't like his question because, to me, it doesn't make much sense.  I mean, I get it, but it seems like a shortsighted question.  But who's judging...? :)