# os._exit(1) or os._exit(0) is not allowing to push logs to AWS cloudwatch

Tags: python, operating-system, try-catch, boto3, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

```
logging.info("outside try, except and finally block")
try:
    logging.info("inside try block")
except:
    logging.info("inside except block")
finally:
    logging.info("inside finally block")
    os._exit(1)
```

Initializing boto3 session and pushing log to cloudwatch using watchtower library in python. if os._exit(1) is used in the program Only `logging.info("outside try, except and finally block")` log is pushed into cloudwatch. So I tried `sys.exit()` now all the logs are pushed into cloudwatch.

```
logging.info("outside try, except and finally block")
try:
    logging.info("inside try block")
except:
    logging.info("inside except block")
finally:
    logging.info("inside finally block")
    sys.exit()
```

Not understanding what is happening with `os._exit(1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between sys.exit(0) and os.\_exit(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591350/what-is-difference-between-sys-exit0-and-os-exit0)

Comment: sys.exit flushes buffers but os._exit does not.