# Viewing python errors in Geany

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, geany

I'm using the Geany editor on a raspberry pi to write a simple program using pi3d

I had a program running, made some changes and now it crashes.

My problem is that when I run the program from Geany, a window opens, an error is printed but before I can read it the screen is cleared and a standard error message is displayed:

```
    --------------------------
    (program exited with code: 1)
    Press return to continue
```

I've tried running the code directly from the terminal, but the same thing happens. I can't scroll up to see the error or anything, it's not visible anywhere.

Is there a way I can get it to either write this to disk, or pause when there's an error so that I can actually read it?

Comment: This is not Python or Geany specific error, [see this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426045/difference-between-exit0-and-exit1-in-python).

Comment: Have you tried redirect stderr to a file, like this `python your_program.py 1>&2 2>error`? Also in console you can scroll up/down by SHIFT+PageUP/PageDOWN

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from @rth sorts it - redirecting the output directly to a file from the shell