# I want to know what exactly sys.exit(-1) returns in python?

Tags: sys

My code goes like this:

```
if (not Y):
    print ("Can't print")
    sys.exit(-1)
```

I am unable to understand what does the argument (`-1`) returns?

Comment: 'if (not api):
     print ("Can't Authenticate")
     sys.exit(-1)'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between exit(0) and exit(1) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426045/difference-between-exit0-and-exit1-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sys.exit(-1)` tells the program to quit. It basically just stops the python code from continuing execution. -1 is just the status code that is passed in. Generally 0 denotes successful execution, any other number (usually 1) means something broke.

Answer (score 4):

The call `sys.exit(n)` tells the interpreter to stop the execution and return `n` to the OS. What this value is depends on the operating system.

For example on UNIX (`$?` is the last exit status):

```
$ python -c "import sys; sys.exit(-1)"
$ echo $?
255
```

This is because it treats the return value as an unsigned 8bit value (see [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/exit-status.html)). On Windows the value would be an unsigned 32bit value (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Windows)) and thus be `4294967295`.

As you can see in the first link, the convention is to return `0` on a successful exit and a non-zero value otherwise. Sometimes you'll see that an application has a certain convention for its status codes.

For example the program `wget` has a section in its man page that tells you why an error occurred:

```
EXIT STATUS
       Wget may return one of several error codes if it encounters problems.

       0   No problems occurred.

       1   Generic error code.

       2   Parse error---for instance, when parsing command-line options, the .wgetrc or .netrc...

       3   File I/O error.

       4   Network failure.

       5   SSL verification failure.

       6   Username/password authentication failure.

       7   Protocol errors.

       8   Server issued an error response.
```

The convention of returning `0` on a success is very helpful for writing scripts:

```
$ if python -c "import sys; sys.exit(-1)"; then echo "Everything fine"; else echo "Not good"; fi
Not good
$ if python -c "import sys; sys.exit(0)"; then echo "Everything fine"; else echo "Not good"; fi
Everything fine
```