# Is there documentation for Airflow log file return codes?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, return-code

I am trying to identify what in a .log file makes a specific task marked as "Successful" vs "Failure" in airflow. I am getting the sense that this is dependent upon the operator (`PythonOperator` vs `EmailOperator` vs `BashOperator` etc.).

I am seeing different return codes. For example, `INFO - Task exited with return code 1` or `INFO - Task exited with return code 0` or `INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=00000, status='terminated') (00000) terminated with exit code -15`

I am not seeing consistency.. I first thought `INFO - Task exited with return code 0` constituted a success, but I see some failure logs also have this.

I would appreciate any insight into understanding different return code #.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that these return codes are equal that exit codes from python.
The meaning of these exit codes are better explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426045/difference-between-exit0-and-exit1-in-python#:%7E:text=0%20and%201%20are%20the%20exit%20codes.&text=exit(1)%20means%20there%20was,why%20the%20program%20is%20exiting.&text=A%20non-zero%20exit%20code,code%20means%20a%20successful%20exit.), but in summary, code 0 means "no errors" in your process, and 1 means that your process has one or more errors.