# How to read %ERRORLEVEL% enviroment variable in python

Tags: python, environment-variables, errorlevel

I need to read (and eventually change) `%ERRORLEVEL%` in my python script, but `os.environ` doesn't contain it. Is there a way to read it from somewhere else?

Comment: Do you understand the percent-signs are not part of the var name? They are cmd.exe syntax for substituting the value of the var name between the percent signs. In a UNIX shell, like bash, the equivalent is `echo $ERRORLEVEL`. So in a program you should use `ERRORLEVEL`.

Comment: @KurtisRader thanks for the info, i didnt know that. But in my program i've been using ```ERRORLEVEL``` and it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%ERRORLEVEL% gives us an understanding if a command which is executed in the CMD  has successfully executed or not.

Let's say, I have a python file

```
import os
elevel = os.system("cd")
print(elevel)
```

Here , the os.system("cd") will give the current directory path and elevel will be 0( 0 says no error while executing the command).

and,

```
import os
elevel = os.system("c")
print(elevel)
```

Here, os.system("c") will give an output like 'c' is not an internal command. The elevel value will be 1 (1 denoting some error while executing the command)

But, I am not sure if you can set the %errorlevel%. maybe you can throw an exception in python and which will make the error level to 1. Or similar way to make it one.

Edit :

from [Difference between exit(0) and exit(1) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426045/difference-between-exit0-and-exit1-in-python)

I found that we can give `exit(1)` , to exit python with an error implying %errorlevel% will be set to one in CMD.

Answer (score 3):

It's working fine for me if you set a System Variable and reference it with

```
os.environ["VARIABLE_NAME"]
```

See below:

[image]

Inside the terminal:

```
C:\Users\ak47>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
true

C:\Users\ak47>python
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import os
>>> os.environ["ERRORLEVEL"]
'true'
>>>
```

Comment: ERRORLEVEL is an existing variable in my system (windows). 
I can read it using the command line for example, but python somehow doesnt see it.