# Returning output from python script to bash variable

Tags: python, bash

I'm relatively new in shell scripting and I wanted to have some clarification on the following.

If i have a python script that does the following:

```
def return_output():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return a+b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    return_output()
```

and say I want to run this script in bash in which I would want to retrieve the output value in bash via a variable:

```
summation=$(python total.py)
echo $summation
```

If i run the following shell script, nothing will be echoed.

However, i notice that when i **change the python code** of "**return a+b**" to "**print(a+b)**" instead, I would get the echoed value of "3" when i run the shell script.

```
3
```

Therefore my question is, if a python script were to be made to execute in a terminal, does it always have to **print** the output instead of using the **return** keyword?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Bash has no (simple) way to communicate with Python other than Python's `stdout`, so you will always have to print the output if you want bash to know what that output is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You'll want to `print(...)` (write to stdout) to capture the output of the script in a variable.

You can, in addition to that, call `sys.exit(0)`, when the script ran successfully or, call `sys.exit(1)` if the script fails. This adheres to [common UNIX CLI patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426045/difference-between-exit0-and-exit1-in-python#answer-9426054).