# python - exit code different than 0 + message:

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit-code

How do I do the following in python?
i.e. Get a status > 0 + message that I want to put out?

```
# code
exit(2, "there is an error in the given path") // Just a string example of course
```

Comment: In python you would `try` something and if it doesn't work you `raise` the appropriate `Exception` with a custom message. Otherwise you can use `sys.exit("there is an error)`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want just throw an exception like what you did in your code, then you can use raise instead.

[Difference between exit(0) and exit(1) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9426054/12533689)

> 0 and 1 are the exit codes.
>
> exit(0) means a clean exit without any errors / problems
>
> exit(1) means there was some issue / error / problem and that is why the program is exiting.
>
> This is not Python specific and is pretty common. A non-zero exit code is treated as an abnormal exit, and at times, the error code indicates what the problem was. A zero error code means a successful exit.
>
> This is useful for other programs, shell, caller etc. to know what happened with your program and proceed accordingly.