# is their a way to close the IDLE shell if they input something

Tags: python, python-idle

is there a way on IDLE to close the users shell if they were to enter something that would be supposed to "quit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exit(0)` to terminate the program, as follows:

```py
while True:
    i = input()
    if i == "quit":
        exit(0)
    else:
        # do something
        pass
```

For more information about what 0 for `exit()` means:
[Difference between exit(0) and exit(1) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426045/difference-between-exit0-and-exit1-in-python/9426054#9426054)